# MySQL REGEXP for numbers that begin with 

Tags: mysql, regex

I need to write a query using MYSQL REGEXP that will find me rows that have a certain column begin with 11 or 12 or etc.  I know I can use LIKE or LEFT(####,2) but would like to use the REGEXP option.  My data is stored as 110001, 122122, 130013a and etc.

EDIT 1:

To make it more clear, I would like to express

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '11%' or column LIKE '12%' or column LIKE '30%'"
```

with REGEXP

Thanks!

Comment: If the value starts with 11 or 12, LIKE is going to perform better than REGEXP.  Bad practice to code for what you like, vs what performs best...

Comment: What do you mean by '11 or 12 or etc."? Do you mean anything starting with two digits? Anything starting with 1 followed by another digit? Any two digits except zero? Something else?

Comment: Wow, man you guys are fast.  I meant to say that I only need rows that have column 1 begin with 11, or 12, or 32, or any combination of 2 digits that I throw at it.  Thanks!

Comment: @OMG Ponies: While I agree, there is also the matter of maintainability. If a particular construct is easier to maintain by a group, it may be worthwhile to sacrifice some performance if the application doesn't demand it. (Just offering a reason why a group might choose something that doesn't perform as well.)

Comment: @JYelton: I understand, but it's something that could be easier to deal with if the design were able to address the issue.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To match rows that start with any two digits you can use:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE yourcolumn REGEXP '^[0-9][0-9]';
```

If you only want to allow rows starting with `11`, `12` or `30` then you could use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE yourcolumn REGEXP '^(11|12|30)';
```

This will not be able to use an index on the column so it may be slower than using LIKE.

Comment: Mark, thanks but this is not what I am looking for.  I need something like "'SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '11%' or column like '12%' or column like '30%'" expressed with REGEXP.